# Is Eigenface best for moving object face recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing a project on face recognition from CCTV cameras, I want to recognize each individual faces. I think eigenface method is best for face recognition. But when we use eigenface method for moving object face recognition, is there any problem? Can we recognize individuals perfectly? Since it is not still image, I am really confused to select a method.
Please help me to know whether this method is ok, otherwise suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Typically those computer vision techniques used in image analysis can be used in video analysis, too.  Videos just give you more information (esp. the temporal information.)  For example, you could do face recognition using multiple frames, and between each frame you do object tracking.  Associating multiple frames typically give you higher accuracy.

IMO, the most difficult problems are: you're more likely to face viewing angle, calibration problems, and lighting condition problems, in which you will need accurate face detection technique, or more training data in order to recognize faces under viewing angles and lighting conditions.  Eigen face based approach relies on an accurate position of faces, eyes, and so on.  Otherwise, you are likely to mix different features in the same vector.  But again, this problem also exists in face recognition under still image.

To sum up, video content only gives you more information.  If you don't really want to associated frames and consider temporal information, video is just a collection of still images :)

Comment: ok,is there any other better method to overcome face viewing angle, calibration problems, and lighting condition etc

Comment: For viewing angle, you need to collect training data to cover different angles.  For calibration, you need more accurate face detection techniques.  But you could also work-around by just simply applying a moving window around a detected face to take multiple images, and use each image as the input to your face recognition engine.  If you're doing real-time analysis, you shouldn't try something too complicated.  Otherwise it's hard to achieve real-time performance.

Comment: Yes.  Just as you use recognize faces in images. Plus you can do object tracking or some temporal analysis stuff.

Comment: This method is not working for a real time application.